# Finding the inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have these matrices:

Find the inverse matrices:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0& 0&\dots & 0& 0\\0 & 1 & 1& 0&\dots & 0& 0  \\0 & 0 & 1& 1&\dots & 0& 0 \\\dots & \dots & \dots& \dots&\dots & \dots& \dots\\0 & 0 & 0& 0&\dots & 1& 1 \\0 & 0 & 0& 0&\dots & 0& 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & a^2& a^3&\dots & a^{n-1}& a^n\\0 & 1 & a& a^2&\dots & a^{n-2}& a^{n-1}  \\0 & 0 & 1& a&\dots & a^{n-3}& a^{n-2} \\\dots & \dots & \dots& \dots&\dots & \dots& \dots\\0 & 0 & 0& 0&\dots & 1& a \\0 & 0 & 0& 0&\dots & 0& 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

These are examples of exam problems I will be facing soon. I want to understand how to solve these type of problems

PS I am new in math and I couldn't find any better resourse if you can link me a good source for linear algebra, that would be great.

Comment: I don't understand your notation, could you write the question with Latex or with an explanation of the notation? Thank you

Comment: You can find the inverse by keeping track of your row operations when row reducing the matrix, try doing it for some small examples, you will see the general pattern. Then prove this general pattern (which should be easy then). Also, then inverses are actually easy matrices.

Comment: the notation: the numbers in grey are just matrices, I have no idea what is Latex..

Comment: The notation is clear (at least to me). You should be able work out both by inspection. (Hint: the first requires an inverse that is upper triangular with entries of alternating sign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the usual algorithm, you can calculate that $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0&\mid&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&\mid&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&\mid&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&\mid&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_3\rightarrow R_3-R_4}\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0&\mid&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&\mid&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&\mid&0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&1&\mid&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\ \xrightarrow{R_2\rightarrow R_2-R_3} \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0&\mid&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&\mid&0&1&-1&1\\
0&0&1&0&\mid&0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&1&\mid&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\ \xrightarrow{R_1\rightarrow R_1-R_2}
 \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&\mid&1&-1&1&-1\\
0&1&0&0&\mid&0&1&-1&1\\
0&0&1&0&\mid&0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&1&\mid&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Do this calculation yourself and try to understand the pattern, then show this pattern for a general matrix of the desired form. The other matrix can be dealt with in much the same fashion.

Comment: I've been trying to this exact thing for the last half an hour.. before the post, I undestand the theory behind finding the inverse matrices but in practice I can't seem to "do the math" :(

Comment: @murloc: I edited my answer to include the operations involved, now the pattern should become very clear.

Answer (score 1):

One algorithm is to start with the "double" matrix
$$
[A \mid I]
$$
where $A$ is the matrix to be inverted and $I$ is the identiy matrix,
and to transform it via elementary row operations, focussing on the left matrix, such that one arrives at
$$
[I \mid B]
$$
it turns out that $B = A^{-1}$.

**Example 1:**
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Starting at the last row and working upwards is the way to go here.

**Example 2:**
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & a & a^2 & a^3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & a & a^2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & a & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & a & a^2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -a^3 \\
0 & 1 & a   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -a^2 \\
0 & 0 & 1   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a \\
0 & 0 & 0   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & a & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -a^2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a   & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1    & -a \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0    & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & -a \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: I understand it in theory but whe I start solving it.. I fail

Comment: @murloc I added an exmaple for your second matrix as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start to obtain a general proof:

For the first matrix $A$: Let $a_{ij}$ denote elements of $A$, $b_{ij}$ elements of its inverse. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{ki}=1$$$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}=0 \quad(i\neq j)$$
And $$b_{n,n}=1$$

$a_{ij}=1$ when $j=i$ or $j=i+1$ and $0$ otherwise, hence:
$$b_{i,i}+b_{i+1,i}=1$$
$$b_{i,j}+b_{i+1,j}=0$$

For $i=n-1$ and $j=n$ we have $$b_{n-1,n}+b_{n,n}=0$$ $$b_{n-1,n}=-1$$
etc...